# Is the AEM core module necessary?

Tags: node.js, maven, aem

I've inherited an aem project which has core, ui.apps, it.tests, and ui.frontend modules. The frontend is nodejs. The core module has java codes, but I don't understand what's using it. Search results for "what core module is used for" returns "Core module contains java codes".

Comment: Your findings are correct. The `core` module, as defined by the AEM project arthetype, contains Java code. It can be used for all sorts of things, from component models to OSGi services implementing arbitrary functionality. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/archetype/using.html?lang=en I'm guessing the downvote stems from the fact that this question could be rephrased as "What does Java code do in an AEM project", which is extremely broad.

Comment: So, based on someone else's response on another thread. The core module isn't mandatory. If you're not writing any java codes, you don't need it.  In my case, the previous owner must have copied someone else's project and left out the java codes event though they're not being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the core module will contain Java-based services - primarily OSGi components with implementation/business logic required by the project. This could be just about anything, from custom servlets intended to directly handle user requests, to scheduled tasks, model POJOs, extensions/plugins for OOTB or third-party frameworks, and many others.

Is this module required? That's hard to answer, since it depends on the project, but generally speaking most non-trivial AEM projects will have some amount of Java implementation.

Most projects nowadays will be using a framework known as [HTL (a.k.a. Sightly)](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/use-api-java.html?lang=en) which is an HTML-esque template language that can invoke Java/server-side code via special HTML attributes. If you see any Java classes that extend `WCMUsePojo`, these will be providing domain logic for some front-end component(s).

If you see classes annotated with `@Component`/`@Service` (there are other annotations but these two are the most common) then those will be providing some kind of back-end functionality. You'd need to look at them case-by-case as they could be doing just about anything.

It really is a broad topic, and you'd be wise to read up on [AEM development in general](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/home.html?lang=en) if you've inherited a project. Hopefully you also inherited a copy of AEM you can spin-up locally to familiarise yourself with the platform and your project.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I don't see anything that extends WCMUsePojo or @Component/ @Service annotations. I excluded the core module and the project still built. I'm also 100% sure the front-end application does not depend on it. Could aem itself be using it for authoring? I should probably mention that the project doesn't have contents, and the frontend module use external apis and jquery.

Comment: It's possible for `core` to contain authoring-related logic, yes. Best thing is to take a look at the code itself, because its implementation-dependent - there could be anything in there.